# RuntimeError: Timeout context manager should be used inside a task, sending discord.py messages outside async function

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py, python-asyncio

I'm making a discord.py bot and I want to create a async function to send a message. However, a I want to call this function from a non-async function.

> **This is the discord client initialization**

```
import requests
import json
from datetime import datetime
import discord
import asyncio
from discord.ext import commands
import firebase_admin
from firebase_admin import credentials, firestore

intents = discord.Intents.all()
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix='&', intents=intents)
```

> **This is my send_message function**

```
async def msg(msg,channel):
        await channel.send(msg)
```

> **This is the non-async function that's calling msg()**

```
def checkStart(doc_snapshot,changes,read_time):
    for change in changes:
        if change.type.name == 'ADDED' or change.type.name == 'MODIFIED':
            anaDoc = change.document.to_dict()
            if anaDoc['start'] == True:
                asyncio.run(msg('Game started!',main_channel[change.document.reference.parent.parent.id]))
                print(change.document.reference.parent.parent.id)
```

> **Traceback**

```
Thread-ConsumeBidirectionalStream caught unexpected exception Timeout context manager should be used inside a task and will exit.  
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Chico\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\google\api_core\bidi.py", line 657, in _thread_main
    self._on_response(response)
  File "C:\Users\Chico\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\google\cloud\firestore_v1\watch.py", line 462, in on_snapshot     
    meth(proto)
  File "C:\Users\Chico\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\google\cloud\firestore_v1\watch.py", line 392, in _on_snapshot_target_change_no_change
    self.push(change.read_time, change.resume_token)
  File "C:\Users\Chico\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\google\cloud\firestore_v1\watch.py", line 568, in push
    self._snapshot_callback(keys, appliedChanges, read_time)
  File "c:\Users\Chico\Documents\newCartola\main.py", line 221, in checkStart
    asyncio.run(msg('Jogo iniciado!',main_channel[change.document.reference.parent.parent.id]))
  File "C:\Users\Chico\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\asyncio\runners.py", line 44, in run
    return loop.run_until_complete(main)
  File "C:\Users\Chico\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 642, in run_until_complete
    return future.result()
  File "c:\Users\Chico\Documents\newCartola\main.py", line 213, in msg
    await channel.send(msg)
  File "C:\Users\Chico\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\abc.py", line 904, in send
    data = await state.http.send_message(channel.id, content, tts=tts, embed=embed,
  File "C:\Users\Chico\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\http.py", line 185, in request
    async with self.__session.request(method, url, **kwargs) as r:
  File "C:\Users\Chico\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\aiohttp\client.py", line 1012, in __aenter__
    self._resp = await self._coro
  File "C:\Users\Chico\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\aiohttp\client.py", line 426, in _request
    with timer:
  File "C:\Users\Chico\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\aiohttp\helpers.py", line 579, in __enter__
    raise RuntimeError('Timeout context manager should be used '
RuntimeError: Timeout context manager should be used inside a task
```

Comment: Can you post the *whole* traceback please?

Comment: You shouldn't really use `asyncio.run` more than *once*, it's supposed to be a main entry point to asyncio based programs.

Comment: @ŁukaszKwieciński so how can i run this async func just once?

Comment: That's not really the answer you want, my solution would be to use `asyncio.create_task`, though this starts it in the "background" without waiting for completion.